# Failed to Create Sound

Tags: lua, coronasdk

Very simple issue but I have no idea if anyone can help me with it. Perhaps it is a bug? I simply want to load this order but get the warning that WARNING: C:\Users\Usuario\Documents\Corona Projects\BalloonTap\game.lua:259: audio.loadSound() failed to create sound 'audio/pop.wav´.

The directory of the audio of the audio file is C:\Users\Usuario\Documents\Corona Projects\BalloonTap\audio

The code is:

```
balloonPop = audio.loadSound( "audio/pop.wav")
```

Any possible fixes? I have tried different audio files and renaming file. I have tried putting it in the main folder and just saying balloonPop = audio.loadSound( "pop.wav") but that fails as well.

Comment: Well done: you included things you've already tried in the question.  That helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When sounds are not loading in Corona, it is a good idea to check that the file can be found:

```
local filename = "audio/pop.wav"
if system.pathForFile( filename , system.ResourceDirectory ) == nil then
    print("WARNING: cannot find audio file "..filename )
end
```

The fact that the sound could not be created suggests, however, that this is not the problem.  From the [Audio Usage/Functions Guide](https://docs.coronalabs.com/guide/media/audioSystem/index.html):

> Cross-platform .wav files must be 16-bit uncompressed.

Is your sound file in the correct format?

Comment: Yes thank you it was. I opened the sound file in audacity and saved it as 16-bit and now its fine.

Comment: Excellent! By the way, if you ever want to use compressed formats (OGG, M4A), be sure to use a format supported by the platform you are building for. [More information here in the guide](https://docs.coronalabs.com/guide/media/audioSystem/index.html#audio-formats)

Comment: Oh, and it's my pleasure @Atrag.  You're very welcome.